# Close covid advertisement before taking screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to take screenshot for few websites. But i need to close the covid advertisement before taking screenshot. [A sample website for reference](https://www.brilinta.com). I have achieved my requirement with the below line of code by using class name of the closing button.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 
20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"close-button"))).click()
```

[Another website](https://www.fasenra.com) with the same covid advertisement but with different class name `covid-close-button`. What is the best possible way to make a generic solution for all the websites irrespective of different class names? Also is there a way to check the existence of these advertisements on website?

Comment: often modals can be closed by clicking the esc key. you culd try sending that

Comment: I'm able to close the modals by sending TAB and ENTER keys. But I'm not able to close the advertisement banners in the same manner.

Comment: It's hard to find a generalized class for that because there is no standard defined and it totally depends on the website to use any class for that. What you can do is try to find some common classes for the close button and search for each of those classes on the page. If found then close it.

Comment: if its the sticky elements at the bottom of the window, then neither of the pages you  listed have one that can be closed. on one it disaperes if you scroll down on the other it wont, it just there. So if you want to remove it you'll have to alter the actual html of the page

Comment: @BendikKnapstad I'm referring to the covid related info banner at the top of the websites.

Comment: @HNMN3 If nothing works for me, then i have to make a dictionary of close button class names and have to search for these names.

Comment: We can also use the list of all close buttons. A better approach would be to find the parent div which would be having a class name very similar to covid19 and then inside that look for button having close in the class name.